# Difference between ModuleID and ModuleUniqueID in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm using the ModuleController class to copy modules to specific pages. I noticed that there are GetModule methods which take ModuleID as an argument and then there's GetModuleByUniqueID.

What's the difference between ModuleID and ModuleUniqueID? (usage not data type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloned Module requires a different uniqueID.The link below will help you to understand.

https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/6d382d62f0719a614c10370efa6dd70be879a644/Website/admin/ControlPanel/AddModule.ascx.cs#L433-L542

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API for this [on GitHub](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/8c90a704c9a251e3c4a848f3e96259b12693c61c/DNN%20Platform/Library/Entities/Modules/ModuleController.cs) it appears that the GetModule methods are done using a manner that pulls from an internal hash, where the ModuleUniqueId call is directly to the database.  Both using the ModuleId value to do the lookup.

You can see this looking at line #1440 and line #1574

Comment: But why does DNN make use of both? What is their purpose and when should you use one over the other?

Comment: That is a bit hard to say. If copying though I'd use the non cached one